# Where did I make the mistake solving systems of complex number variables?

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I was given the system: $$I_1(6+7.5j)+I_28j=10$$ and $$I_2(1+11j)+I_18j=0$$

From the first equation, I solve for $I_1$: $$I_1=\frac{10-I_28j}{6+7.5j}$$

I plug this into the second equation: $$I_2(1+11j)+\frac{8j(10-I_28j)}{6+7.5j}=0$$  $$I_2(1+11j)+\frac{80j+64I_2}{6+7.5j}=0$$ $$I_2+I_211j+\frac{(80j+I_264)(6-7.5j)}{92.25}=0$$ $$I_2+I_211j+\frac{480j+600+I_2256-I_2480j}{92.25}=0$$ $$I_2+I_211j+5.2j+6.5+I_2 2.8-I_25.2j=0$$ Combine the like terms, $$I_2 3.8+I_2 5.8j=-6.5-5.2j$$ Finally, $$I_2=\frac{-6.5-5.2j}{3.8+5.8j}=\frac{8.3\angle 219^{\circ}}{6.9\angle57^{\circ}}=1.2\angle 162^{\circ}=-1.14+j0.37$$

But the textbook has the answer $$I_2=-0.94+0.17j$$

Comment: I take it that you use $j$ to denote the imaginary unit (usually $i$)?

Comment: That is the "electrical engineer's" notation for $i$. That's because $i$ is often used to indicate current.

Comment: Yes. That is right. It is the sqrt of -1.

Comment: I suspect the algebra would have been easier, and less prone to error, if you had solved for $I_1$ in the *second* equation (which only has two terms) and plugged it in to the first equation (which has three).  In general, I find that the algebra is easier if I solve a simpler equation and plug it in to a more complicated one, rather than vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I_2+I_211j+\frac{480j+600+I_2256-I_2480j}{92.25}=0$ is incorrect, should be $I_2+I_211j+\frac{480j+600+I_2(384 - 480j)}{92.25}=0$